# MongoDB Find in the Array in object

Tags: mongodb

Record ::

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5526040fc58e95b598cf1bc6"),
    "group" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71dbb47628dd9e2882e0",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "A1",
                "un" : "robot20",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }, 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71ddb47628dd9e2882e1",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "A2",
                "un" : "robot21",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }
        ], 
        [ 
            {
                "userId" : "551cd7656c55761724e3a0e0",
                "socketid" : "cInGsNcr9G9OMvVyAAAA",
                "group_name" : "B1",
                "un" : "Hardik Ranapariya",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90"
            }, 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71deb47628dd9e2882e2",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "B2",
                "un" : "robot22",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }
        ], 
        [ 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71e0b47628dd9e2882e3",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "C1",
                "un" : "robot23",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }, 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71e1b47628dd9e2882e4",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "C2",
                "un" : "robot24",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }
        ], 
        [ 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71e3b47628dd9e2882e5",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "D1",
                "un" : "robot25",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }, 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71e8b47628dd9e2882e8",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "D2",
                "un" : "robot28",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }
        ]
    ],
    "group2" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71ddb47628dd9e2882e1",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "A2",
                "un" : "robot21",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }
        ], 
        [ 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71e1b47628dd9e2882e4",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "C2",
                "un" : "robot24",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }, 
            {
                "userId" : "551b71e8b47628dd9e2882e8",
                "socketid" : "",
                "group_name" : "D2",
                "un" : "robot28",
                "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
                "is_robot" : true
            }
        ]
    ],
    "group3" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "551b71e1b47628dd9e2882e4",
            "socketid" : "",
            "group_name" : "C2",
            "un" : "robot24",
            "pp" : "https://graph.facebook.com/347571208785861/picture?height=90&width=90",
            "is_robot" : true
        }
    ],
    "status" : 1
}
```

And I want to find this record using `userId` in the group array.

Here, userId is array in array and then object.
so please help to solve out this to me..

i also try this following query for that to find

```
db.test.find({'group.user':'551b71dbb47628dd9e2882e0'})
```

but it's not working.

thanks in advance..

Comment: *it's not working*: Any more details about the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finding nested array of array documents use mongo [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/). Query as below

```
db.collectionName.find({"group":{"$elemMatch":
                       {"$elemMatch":{"userId":"551b71dbb47628dd9e2882e0"}}}},
                       {"group.$":1}
                       ).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake,

```
db.test.find({'group.userId':'551b71dbb47628dd9e2882e0'})
```

user => userId.

And you can also the "$elemMatch" operation:

```
db.test.find (
     {group:
         { $elemMatch: {userId:"551b71dbb47628dd9e2882e0"}}
     },
     {"group.$":1}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As the its involves querying nested array elements you can do with the below if you know the index of the array.

**Note** : operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array([See for more](http://operator%20cannot%20be%20used%20for%20queries%20which%20traverse%20more%20than%20one%20array))

```
db.test.find({"group": {"$elemMatch": {"0.userId": "551b71dbb47628dd9e2882e0"}}})
```